# VSCode: how to scroll through IntelliSense overload signature suggestions

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

VSCode: how to scroll through IntelliSense overload signatures in TypeScript and in Javascript ?

Sometimes the IntelliSense hints e.g. (+1 overload) in a tooltip as you write "someObj.someMethod(" and shows one (first) overload, but how to see the other overloads ?

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Your screenshot shows the hover tooltip for a method call, which only shows the overload that is actually being used.  The only way I know of to see all overloads is in "parameter hints".  The parameter hints appear automatically when you type the opening parenthesis of the method call, or you can put the cursor between the parentheses and invoke the "Trigger Parameter Hints" command, normally bound to Ctrl+Shift+Space.  The parameter hints pop-up has two small arrow buttons you can click to navigate through the overloads:

[image: screenshot showing method tooltip and overload navigation buttons]

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + [spacebar] is a keyboard shortcut worth mentioning to trigger the IntelliSense and it works exactly as explained by @Matt. I added a screenshot for the IntelliSense view I am asking for (screenshot from Jasmine spec file for Angular in JS) which is another view and different from the one described by Matt

Comment: I think the answer is "just use Ctrl + Shift + Space".  I clarified my answer.

Comment: You are the heroes!

Comment: Use the arrow keys up and down to browse the overloads aside from clicking on the arrows